# How to get values of changed text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I click on the link in a GridView, it will redirect me to another page and pass a parameter at the same time.

code is as shown at below.

```
    <ItemTemplate>  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditAnnouncement" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("annID") %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>  
    </ItemTemplate>
```

This is the code in vb

```
    Response.Redirect("editmemannouncement.aspx?annID=" + e.CommandArgument)
```

This is the directed page

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    param1 = Request.QueryString("annID")  
    //search record using the "annID" (will only get 1 record)  
    TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("anntitle").ToString
```

User may change the text in TextBox2. In the directed page, there is also a button. When I click on the button, I want to get the changed text in TextBox2. I tried

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox2.Text
```

but I only get back the original value instead of the changed value. How can I get the changed value from TextBox2.Text

Answer (score 0):

On every page load you set again the TextBox2, so even if you do have change it, you do not see the changes because you overwrite it.

Use the [`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to not overwrite it when you make post back as:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not IsPostBack 
   param1 = Request.QueryString("annID")  

   //search record using the "annID" (will only get 1 record)  
   TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("anntitle").ToString 
End If
```

Comment: @SurajSingh Because here was (now have delete his answer) a user that make vote manipulations (vote him self) and I point at him, and is upset right now :). This answer is correct, is the first, and also is the only on VB as the question is marked

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your code inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`  section ,

```
  If Not IsPostBack
   param1 = Request.QueryString("annID")  
    //search record using the "annID" (will only get 1 record)  
    TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("anntitle").ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`IsPostBack` : Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

```
Sub Page_Load
   If Not IsPostBack
     param1 = Request.QueryString("annID")  
     TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("anntitle").ToString 
   End If
End Sub
```